# Unity Tweak Tool - how to migrate settings to another machine?

Tags: unity, 16.04, customization, unity-tweak-tool

I'm trying to do my custom Ubuntu image (just my own fork just for me :) ).I already implement all neccesary software and my own tweaks and addings, and now I need somehow migrate Compiz and Unity Tweak Tool Settings to complete it (I want to change not just name of distro and add some settings but also I want to customize it fully in visual part using additional themes, cursors, icons, themes, etc to have it complete look). I'm using Cubic so only terminal is available. I managed to migrate my settings for Compiz using:

```
dconf dump /org/compiz/profiles/unity/ > backup.ini

dconf load /org/compiz/profiles/unity/ > backup.ini
```

And this worked. Is there any way to do the same for Unity Tweak Tool? The idea is that I'm going install via terminal some .deb packages with themes which already installed on my own machine and import settings from mine Unity Tweak Tool to use all my settings in my future distro. Can someone help me with that? Maybe there is also some way to do that using `dconf` like I used for Compiz?

Comment: There is no easy way. Unity Tweak Tool does not support this (yet anyway) and it modifies too many different keys to dump easily.

Comment: It appears those are system files so save them as part of your custom spin or place the config files from $HOME in /etc/skel